# C++ inside of C# performance of communication

Tags: c#, c++, communication

I have a program that is coded in c# (Let's call it ValidationChecker). This ValidationChecker needs the OMPL Library which can only be used by python or c++. Therefore a c++ solution was generated which is compiled to a .exe.

The ValidationChecker starts the exe and opens an TCP Communication between itself and the .exe. Afterwards the ValidationChecker is sending some start data to the exe over the tcp communication an the exe is generating some data out of the start data. In some process after creating one new data package, this data is converted by the exe and afterwards sent to the ValidationChecker for checking if this new generated data is valid. So the exe waits until the ValidationCecker sends back the confirmation if this data is valid or not valid. This is a loop until the exe has generated enough valid data packages.

My problem is now:
The whole loop from the creation of the a new data package until the ValidationChecker sends the confirmation takes up to 120ms. The numbers of data packages that has to be created variate between 100 up to 3000. First I did some analysis and noticed that the process of converting the data took up to 60-70ms so I optimized this process and now this process just takes 1-2ms.(first I did some embedding python and now I call a dll instead) My thought was that this will speed up my loop. But the whole loop still takes 120ms and I wonder why? So my measurment of the durations showed, that the converting of data is now faster but the communication for sending the data to c# is slower, nearly exact the percentage of the reduction.

I thought about integrating the c++ solution directly into the ValidationChecker, but I'm not quite sure if this is really possible. I read something over pinvoke, com objects and generating a dll out of my c++ solution. But is this really speeding up my communication between the c# program and the c++ calculation or could this be slower than the actual tcp communication? And another problem is, that there is a need for exchanging data not just by calling a function and return some value. There is one c# function that has to call a c# function for validation checking and needs a return value for the confirmation if this data is valid or not.

So much text I hope you understand my thoughts and could help me with a faster solution. Because I'm not quite sure if I could call a c# function inside of a dll. And if this solution is faster than the solution with the tcp before.

Comment: I would use p/invoke in order to call the C++ dll from C# instead of using a tcp connection.

Comment: So is there a way to call a C# function out of a C++ dll?Or how would you manage this? Is p/invoke really faster than a tcp connection?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you question a bit. You try to call C# code from your C++ code. Now, this is not done by P/invoke. But maybe this helps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736 (I think this is faster than TCP connection)

Comment: No my fault! The problem is that I have two functions. One C# and one C++. But I want to integrate the C++ inside of the C#. Therefore I read that I have to generate a dll out of my C++ code. But inside of the function I need some exchange possibility to call a C# function to check the data. So the process is C# calls C++ function inside DLL this C++ function calls C# function for validation and sends confirmation back.

Comment: Then you will use P/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Because of you did not add any code what kind of functions you have, I will give you a simple example of how to use P/Invoke in order to call a unmanaged library in C#. P/invoke is much faster than a TCP connection, the only overhead for P/invoke is the paramter conversion that must be done.

In the example you see `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` which instructs the runtime to convert the return value as bool. This is needed to get correct values. This could be used also for the method parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 class BeepSample
 {
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     static extern bool Beep(uint dwFreq, uint dwDuration);

     static void Main()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Testing PC speaker...");
         var success = Beep(200, 5);
         Console.WriteLine("Testing complete. " + success);
     }
```

Comment: If P/Invoke happens not to be sufficient for your needs, take a look at C++/CLI.

Comment: Ok this is now what i also saw in some other examples but the big question mark for me now is how to call then from the "inside of a dll" a c# function in this example? or is this not possible?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "inside of a dll". Could you update your question maybe with code or image to explain more exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The "built-in" way to do this (without having to P/Export from C#) is to export an "entry point" from your C++ DLL. The problem there is that C# can't really use C++ directly, so you will need a *clean C* interface (you can't use any C++ stuff in the method signature).

From C++ you can do something along the lines of:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct PackageRequest
    {
        LPWSTR SomeString;
        int32_t SomeInt;
    };

    struct PackageResult
    {
        LPWSTR SomeString;
        int32_t SomeInt;
    };

    __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT DoSomething(PackageRequest& request, PackageResult& response)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then in C#:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    public struct PackageRequest
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public StringBuilder SomeString;
        public int SomeInt;
    }

    public struct PackageReponse
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public StringBuilder SomeString;
        public int SomeInt;
    }

    [DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
    private static extern int DoSomething(ref PackageRequest req, out PackageReponse resp);

    public static PackageReponse DoSomething(PackageRequest req)
    {
        PackageReponse resp;
        var rc = DoSomething(ref req, out resp);
        if (rc != 0)
            throw new Exception("...");
        return resp;
    }
}
```